# What is the clean way to consolidate a large block of argument handling?

Tags: c++

I am trying to clean up a piece of code which will parse command line prompts in order to run specific functions. The original intent of this tool was to be the highest level interface which calls multiple lower level tools to accomplish various tasks. The problem is when the tool began to have more and more features I ended up with a huge block of argument parsing.

```
if (cmdParseOption(&argc, &argv, "-doit0"))
{
    flag = 0;
}
else if (cmdParseOption(&argc, &argv, "-doit1"))
{
    flag = 1;
}
else if (ecmdParseOption(&argc, &argv, "-doit2"))
{
   flag = 2;
   var = 1;
}
```

This goes on for about 30 different commands, which looks horrible and I tend to just dislike large else/if blocks in code. Is there a cleaner way of accomplish large command parsing? Considering switch/case statements but wanted to see if anyone knew of a better way. Most of the cases are simply setting a few variables which are handled later on in general functions.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the third argument of `cmdParseOption()` is a `const char *`.

In any version of C++,

```
#include<string>
#include <map>
typedef void (*function)();

void func1() {};   // we want to call this function for "-doit1"
void func2() {};   // we want to call this function for "-doit2"

int main()
{
      std::map<std::string, function>  option_map;
      option_map["-doit1"] = func1;
      option_map["-doit2"] = func2;
          // etc

      for (std::map<std::string>::const_iterator i = option_map.begin(), end = option_map.end(); i != end; ++i)
      {
            if (cmdParseOption(&argc, &argv, i->first.c_str())
            {
                 //  we've found a match in the map.  Call the corresponding function

                 (i->second)();
            }
      }
      return 0;
}
```

If you want 30 or 300 options, all that needs to change is setting up the map - the loop stays the same.

In C++11 and later, this can be simplified a bit

```
#include<string>
#include <map>
typedef void (*function)();

void func1() {};   // we want to call this function for "-doit1"
void func2() {};   // we want to call this function for "-doit2"

int main()
{
      std::map<std::string, function>  option_map{
                {"-doit1", func1},
                {"-doit2", func2}
                };

      for (auto &i : option_map)
      {
            if (cmdParseOption(&argc, &argv, i.first.c_str())
            {
                 (i.second)();
            }
      }
      return 0;
}
```

If you want other types of callback, there are a wealth of options - both in terms of function types, and facilities in the standard library.

If you want to introduce another check (e.g. calling `ecmdParseOption()` instead of `cmdParseOption()` in your second `else if`) simply set up a second map, populate it, and iterate over it as needed.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Had a feeling that vectors/maps might solve my issue but didn't have a lot of experience with them. Thanks!